# javascriptのprototypeの使い方

Tags: javascript

最近、javascriptを勉強しているものです。
既存のプラグインを改変しようとしているのですが、
オリジナルのソースをいじらずに改造できるかな？と模索しております。

関数を上書きするように自分の処理を挿入できるかな？と思っております。

なにか他にいい方法があればご教授願います。

よろしくお願いします。

HTMLソースです。

```
<div id="hogehoge">
</div>
```

javascriptはこんなかんじです。

```
<script>
(
  function(arg)
  {
    arg(jQuery);
  }
  (
    function($)
    {
      function Hoge(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.bazz();
      }

      Hoge.prototype.bazz = function() {
        var msg = this.foo();
        this.element.html("<h1>" + msg + "</h1>");
      }

      Hoge.prototype.foo = function() {
        var msg = "hello Japan"
        return msg;
      }

      $.fn.call_me = function() {
        hoge = new Hoge(this);
        return hoge;
      }
    }
  )
);

var local_hoge = $("#hogehoge").call_me();
/*
  ここでlocal_hogeを使って、fooのmsgに" and America !"を追加したいです。
  嘘コード：
  local_hoge.prototype.foo = function(){ 
     var msg = super // 元のコードの呼び出しのつもり
     msg += " and America !";
     return msg;
  }
*/
</script>
```

Comment: `local_hoge`の`foo`だけを上書きしたいのでしょうか。それともすべての`foo`の呼び出しを書き換えるということでしょうか。

Comment: `local_hoge` が作成された時には既に望む動作は終わってますから、処理をインサートするには、プラグイン部分の中に書く必要があるように思います。`hoge.element.html("<h1>" + hoge.foo() + " and America !</h1>");`とは書けるでしょうけど。

Comment: 目的の助けにはならないと思いますが、プロトタイプには`__proto__`でアクセスできます。

Comment: すべての`foo`の呼び出しを書き換えるということです。
`local_hoge`が作成された時点では処理がおわっていますので、
元のプログラムを触るしかなさそうです。

Comment: 元のプラグイン部分でコンストラクタからメソッドを呼び出しているのを`call_me`の時点でメソッドを呼び出すようにすべきであるように思います。そうすれば、元のクラスをいじることなくサブクラスを追加するような感じで追加できると思います。

Answer (score 1):

書き換えをそのものがあまり良い方法ではありませんが、一応以下のようにして`prototype`の書き換えを行うことができます。

```js
(
    function(arg) {
        arg(jQuery);
    }
    (
        function($) {
            function Hoge(element) {
                this.element = element;
                this.bazz();
            }

            Hoge.prototype.bazz = function() {
                var msg = this.foo();
                this.element.html("<h1>" + msg + "</h1>");
            }

            Hoge.prototype.foo = function() {
                var msg = "hello Japan"
                return msg;
            }

            $.fn.call_me = function() {
                hoge = new Hoge(this);
                return hoge;
            }
        }
    )
);

var local_hoge = $("#hogehoge").call_me();

(function(local_hoge) {
    var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(local_hoge);
    var orig_func = proto.foo;
    proto.foo = function() {
        var msg = orig_func();
        msg += " and America !";
        return msg;
    };
})(local_hoge);

$("#hogehoge").call_me();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hogehoge">
</div>
```